# Error in this piece of code with the copy constructor - C++08

Tags: c++, constructor

Suppose I have the following (very rough) code

```
class foo
{    
    public:
    int a;
    foo()  //Regular constructor
    {
        ......
        std::cout << "Regular \n";
    }

    foo(foo& f) //Copy constructor with with non-const parameter
    {
      ....
      std::cout << "Copy Constructor \n" ;
    }


    foo& operator= (const foo& f)
    {
         std::cout << "Copy Assignment Operator \n" ;
         return *this;
    }

};


foo makeFoo()
{
   return foo();
}


int main()
{
   foo a = makeFoo();   
}
```

Now when attempting to simulate this code with the `-fno-elide-constructors` (for experimental and educational purpose) I get the following errors

```
main.cpp: In function 'foo makeFoo()':
main.cpp:32:15: error: no matching function for call to 'foo::foo(foo)'
    return foo();
               ^
main.cpp:32:15: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:12:5: note: foo::foo(foo&)
     foo( foo& f)
     ^
main.cpp:12:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'foo' to 'foo&'
main.cpp:10:5: note: foo::foo()
     foo() { std::cout << "Regular \n";}
     ^
main.cpp:10:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:40:20: error: no matching function for call to 'foo::foo(foo)'
    foo a = makeFoo();   //Move constrcutor - Move Constructor  or with copy elision only regular constrcutor
                    ^
main.cpp:40:20: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:12:5: note: foo::foo(foo&)
     foo( foo& f)
     ^
main.cpp:12:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'foo' to 'foo&'
main.cpp:10:5: note: foo::foo()
     foo() { std::cout << "Regular \n";}
     ^
main.cpp:10:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
main.cpp: In function 'foo makeFoo()':
main.cpp:33:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Now these errors are resolved by making the parameter of the copy constructor a const type. I wanted to know if my understanding of why making the parameter of the copy constructor  a const type fixes this problem. Please let me know if my understanding or reasoning is incorrect. Now in the method `makeFoo` after the execution of the statement `return foo();` regular constructor of foo is called. Then the copy constructor of foo is called. Now in my code I have something like this:

```
   foo a = makeFoo();
```

In this case the copy constructor of the `foo a` is called. since the return type of makeFoo() is an rvalue which is always a constant and the copy constructor of foo is a non-const thus an error is generated as we are attempting to pass a constant reference type to a non-constant reference type.

Comment: The input parameter of a conforming copy constructor should be declared as `const`, eg: `foo(const foo& f)`.  A non-`const` reference cannot bind to a temporary object (ie, an rvalue), but a `const` reference can. That is why your `makeFoo()` code is failing.

Comment: @Remy Not quite, a copy constructor can accept non-`const` arguments (§12.8/2). It simply isn’t the *canonical* copy constructor then.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that the copy cnstr should always be a const. I am merely testing my understanding of a case ( a dumb one ) here.

Comment: What exactly is "C++08"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, in your expression  `foo a = makeFoo();`  makeFoo() is an rvalue.

Constructor with non-const input parameter (your case) can only bind lvalue. In fact, `makeFoo()` returns a temporary objects created by the compiler, and the compiler doesn't want you to modify this temporary object that can be deleted at any moment. So the compiler will throw an error when you try to pass an rvalue to a constructor with non-const input parameter.

Constructor with const input parameter can bind rvalue and lvalue.